# After OutPut displayed in linux , how can i see from begining

Tags: linux

This is my Output using system.out.println  which i got in Linux Server .
The problem is taht , i am not able to view the output from serial number 1 , as the below occupies the entire screen .

**please tell me how can i scroll to top ??**

```
341:allitems: tq_relation
342:allitems: tr_num
343:allitems: trader_id
344:allitems: tradetick
345:allitems: trading_state
346:allitems: treas_shrs
347:allitems: treas_stk
348:allitems: treasury_yield
349:allitems: trend
350:allitems: uask_quote
351:allitems: uask_quote_date
352:allitems: ubid_quote
353:allitems: ubid_quote_date
354:allitems: under_cusip
355:allitems: undersymbol
356:allitems: unique_symbol
357:allitems: unit_measure
358:allitems: unpriced
359:allitems: unsolicited
360:allitems: valoren
361:allitems: value_pr_shortinterest
362:allitems: value_shortinterest
363:allitems: vega
364:allitems: vl
365:allitems: vol
366:allitems: volatility12
367:allitems: vwap
368:allitems: wanted_off_bid_ind
369:allitems: wk52hi
370:allitems: wk52hidate
371:allitems: wk52hidate_t
372:allitems: wk52lo
373:allitems: wk52lodate
374:allitems: wk52lodate_t
375:allitems: wkinprog
376:allitems: xchg
377:allitems: xdate
378:allitems: xday
379:allitems: xmonth
380:allitems: xyear
381:allitems: yield
```

Comment: Could you be more specific from what this is a output. If this is a output on a terminal like program you can simply can pipe the output to a pager like less or more like this `myprogramm|less`

Comment: Ya , the output is being displayed in more than one page , so please tell me how can i see the output page wise ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Power of Linux is that you are able to redirect in and output of certain commands to other commands as using the output of program 1 as input for program 2. This can be archived by using:

```
program1|program2
```

and more specific you could use a pager like less  or more. With the **less** command you are able to scroll back and forth and search specific patterns in the output. The **more** command displays the output page wise. The next page of the file is displayed by hitting the *enter* key. For your purpose all you have to to is using.

```
myprogram|less
```

or

```
myprogram|more
```

whatever you prefer. The other approach is to redirect the output to a file. You can do this with the Redirection Operator >  and

```
myprogramm > log.txt
```

will log the output log.txt.

There is even a third method using the script command. When you are typing

```
script log.txt
```

at least in bash this would open a subshell and every input and output that is will get logged to log.txt. You can close and afterwards access the logile by using **exit**. In the last two cases you can view the log.txt file with you favorite text editor or pager.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output of you program to a text file:

```
$ ./myprogram >output.txt
```

Then view the text file with any text editor you like.

You can also pipe the result to the `more` command:

```
$ ./myprogram | more
```

Comment: Currently there are no log file concept , its only being displayed using System.out.println